# Log4Net on MVC.NET using Ninject

Tags: asp.net-mvc, log4net, ninject

I'm trying to set up Log4Net in a MVC.net project with Ninject.
I've reached the point where I'm able to see the Ninject debug output but I am still not seeing any logging output.

This is all running on my localhost so there shouldn't be any issues with security.

The setup I have is as follows:

In the AssemblyInfo.cs I have added this to point log4net to Web.config for configuration

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "Web.config", Watch = true)]
```

In the Web.config I've added the following sections

```
    <configSections>
       <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
    </configSections>

...
    <appSettings>
       <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
    </appSettings>
...
  <log4net>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <file value="log-file.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <encoding value="utf-8" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.SimpleLayout" />
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

In my base controller, from which all the other controllers in the system inherit I have the following:

```
[Inject]
public ILogger logger { get; set; }
```

I then put an explicit throw new Exception("testException") on the login page to force an error which I would have expected to see showing up in the log file.

From the debug trace I see the following on startup.

```
log4net: log4net assembly [log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821]. Loaded from [C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\portal\63a118bb\781d84b7\assembly\dl3\40d137a6\9fb44da2_c951cc01\log4net.dll]. (.NET Runtime [4.0.30319.235] on Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1)
log4net: DefaultRepositorySelector: defaultRepositoryType [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
log4net: DefaultRepositorySelector: Creating repository for assembly [Ninject.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7]
log4net: DefaultRepositorySelector: Assembly [Ninject.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7] Loaded From [C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\portal\63a118bb\781d84b7\assembly\dl3\edd36351\91af46a2_c951cc01\Ninject.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.dll]
log4net: DefaultRepositorySelector: Assembly [Ninject.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7] does not have a RepositoryAttribute specified.
log4net: DefaultRepositorySelector: Assembly [Ninject.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7] using repository [log4net-default-repository] and repository type [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
log4net: DefaultRepositorySelector: Creating repository [log4net-default-repository] using type [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
```

I have the feeling that this is probably a configuration issue but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you instructing Ninject to instantiate an ILog? Just because you have that property you´re expecting to get your exceptions logged? You should catch them and explicitly log them using logger.Error("Some message", ex). Consider using an action filter that logs unhandled exceptions.

Comment: you using the Ninject.extensions.logging?

Answer (score 0):

Injecting an `ILog` or `ILogger` instance does not implicitly register any kind of exception handler.  It just gives you access to a logger.  You still have to tell it what to log and when to log it.

If you want to test your configuration, make a logging call from one of your controller's actions, or use one of the `OnAction` event invokers.  This should probably do what you want:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (Logger != null)
        {
            string message = string.Format("Action executed: {0}.{1}",
                context.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName,
                context.ActionDescriptor.ActionName);
            Logger.Log(typeof(MyController), log4Net.Core.Level.Trace,
                message, context.Exception);
        }
        base.OnActionExecuted(context);
    }

    [Inject]
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }
}
```

That will log every controller action - including exceptions. If you only care about exceptions then either check the `context.Exception` and `context.ExceptionHandled` properties before logging, or better yet write a custom ActionFilter to do this.